# dotnet run attempts to run from a nonexistent path

Tags: .net-core, dotnet-cli

Trying to run my project on my Ubuntu 16.04 server, I get an error:

```
$ dotnet -v run
Telemetry is: Enabled
Project TwitchbotCommons (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1) was previously compiled. Skipping compilation.
Project ohbot-core (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1) was previously compiled. Skipping compilation.
Running /home/ventic/ohbot-core/ohbot-core/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/ubuntu.16.04-x64/ohbot-core --additionalprobingpath /home/ventic/.nuget/packages
No such file or directory
```

Files under bin after the project is compiled.

```
$ tree bin
bin
└── Debug
    └── netcoreapp1.1
        ├── ohbot-core.deps.json
        ├── ohbot-core.dll
        ├── ohbot-core.pdb
        ├── TwitchbotCommons.dll
        └── TwitchbotCommons.pdb

$ dotnet --version
1.0.0-preview2-1-003177
```

Project.json

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1",
        "System.Collections.Specialized": "4.3.0",
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets": "1.0.0",
        "TwitchbotCommons": "*"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "netcoreapp1.1": {}
    },
    "runtimes": {
        "win": {},
        "ubuntu.16.04-x64": {},
        "ubuntu.16.10-x64": {},
        "debian.8-x64": {}
    }
}
```

Why is dotnet core outputting the project in a different directory than it attempts to run it from? How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show your project.json? Did you compile your code using dotnet build or using some IDE?

Comment: @svick dotnet build, added project.json to the question body